# Do I want a @protocol declaration or something else to make sure sub-class defines selectors?

Tags: iphone, ios, protocols, selector

I have a class that does some generic code for Writing to a Database. Bring up the popovers, and controls, etc.  Though there are many types of elements that I can write out to the database, each sub-class needs to have its own     `-(void) writeTagValue` selector to implement the element's write.

The base-class has a selector that does the call to `self.writeTagValue` though since the base class does not really do any writing, its `-(void) writeElement` selector is empty with an  `abort();` in it.

I've implemented a protocol in the base class.h

```
@protocol IoUISEWriteAnimation <NSObject>
  -(void) writeTagValue;
  -(IBAction)saWriteValue:(NSNotification *)notification;
@end
```

added the protocol to the Sub-classes and now if the sub-classes don't define the selectors, I get compiler warnings.

What I want to know is, is there a way to remove the empty `-(void) writeElement` selector  in the base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@protocol MyProtocol<NSObject>

@required 
-(void) myRequiredMethod;

@optional
-(void) myOptionalMethod;

@end
```

And when you need to call an optional method, you do something like this:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myOptionalMethod)])
   [delegate myOptionalMethod];
else
   // abort, or ignore.
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps me out. Base class has common code for 10 sub-classes. the base class calls `[self writeTagValue];`  `writeTagValue` is defined in all sub-classes. When I compile of course it complains that it can't find `writeTagValue` in the base class. so I implemented one, though its empty and should never really get called.  Just seems like there should be a way to not have to have the empty selector in the base class and let the base class know its abstract and someone else will define it along the line.

Comment: Sadly there is no real support for abstract classes in objective-c.

Comment: I would make the base class implementation throw an exception - that way you can tell if you (or a fellow developer) have forgotten to override it in a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the implementation class implement the required methods in the protocol, your base class does not need an empty implementation of that method. However, since it's required, the base class cannot specify that it implements the protocol.

You're on the right path.